# Laravel 4 Polymorphic with multiple Pivot Tables

Tags: php, many-to-many, laravel-4, pivot-table, polymorphism

I'm trying to create a polymorphic relationship with multiple pivot tables. I have a table of requirements that can be assigned to accounts, roles, trips, and countries. This needs to be a many to many relationship because the same requirement could apply to multiple countries and/or trips and/or accounts etc.

I then need a table listing outstanding requirements for the user. For example: if a user has a certain account and there are requirements related to that account, then those requirements would be added to the user's list of requirements.

One solution I have is to first assign the requirements to the accounts, roles, trips, and countries using Pivot tables in a Many to Many relationship. Then using a polymorphic relationship I would connect the user to whichever pivot tables relate.

But I don't know how to do this or if it is even possible?

Here are my tables:

**user_requirements**
- id
- user_id
- requireable_id
- requireable_type

**account_requirement**
- id
- account_id
- requirement_id

**role_requirement**
- id
- role_id
- requirement_id

**trip_requirement**
- id
- account_id
- requirement_id

**country_requirement**
- id
- account_id
- requirement_id

Comment: Here's a similar post:
[laravel-manytomany-multiple][1]
Could you answer that post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966465/laravel-manytomany-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 4.1 now has support for polymorphic many to many relationships.

Example below shows how I have implemented sharing Photos with both Products and Posts.

**DB Schema**

photos

```
id              integer
filename        string
alt             string
```

photoable

```
id              integer
photoable_id    integer
photoable_type  string
```

**Models**

Photo Model

```
class Photo extends Eloquent
{
public function products(){
    return $this->morphedByMany('Product', 'photoable');
}

public function posts(){
    return $this->morphedByMany('Post', 'photoable');
}
}
```

Product Model

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
public function photos(){
    return $this->morphToMany('Photo', 'photoable');
}
}
```

Post Model

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
public function photos(){
    return $this->morphToMany('Photo', 'photoable');
}
}
```

With the above, I can access all photos which are attached to a product as follows:

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$productPhotos = $product->photos()->all();
```

I can also iterate over to display all photos as any collection of models.

```
foreach ($productPhotos as $photo)
{
    // Do stuff with $photo
}
```

The above can be replicated almost exactly to your requirements.

1. create a `requirements` table
2. create a `requireable` table
3. In `Requirement` model, declare all morphedByMany relationships
4. In Country, Trip, Role etc. declare morphToMany relationships

nb - I've typed this out freehand in S/O with no code editor, so there will probably be a typo, error or two - but concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

A [polymorphic relation in Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) is intended for single MODEL associations, therefore you cannot achieve what you are trying to build with this method. This is due to the fact that a pivot table doesn't represent a Model.