# Laravel ManyToMany Multiple

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have 3 models: `User`, `Role`, `Tool` where each user could have many roles, and each role could have many tools.

The many to many relationships work well in each case. I can access:

```
User::find(1)->roles
Tool::find(1)->roles
Role::find(1)->tools
Role::find(1)->users
```

My tables are:

```
users
 id
 name

roles
 id
 name

tools
 is
 name

role_user
 id
 role_id
 user_id

role_tool
 id
 role_id
 tool_id
```

In each model:

```
//In User Model
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('Rol');
}

//In Role Model
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

public function tools()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('Tool');
}

//In Tool Model
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('Rol');
}
```

I need to get all the tools of a single user like: `User::find(1)->roles()->tools`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the roles of the user, then in a loop you get all tools of the role and merge them to an array where you store all tools.

```
$tools = array();
foreach(User::find(1)->roles as $role)
    $tools = array_merge($tools, $role->tools->toArray());
```

This runs a query for every iteration, so for better performance you should use eager loading.

```
$tools = array();
foreach (User::find(1)->load('roles.tools')->roles as $role) {
    $tools = array_merge($tools, $role->tools->toArray());
}
```

Now you can place this to a function called `tools()` in your `User` model.

```
public function tools()
{
    $tools = array();   
    foreach ($this->load('roles.tools')->roles as $role) {
        $tools = array_merge($tools, $role->tools->toArray());
    }
    return $tools;
}
```

You can call it like this: `User::find(1)->tools()`.

I don't think that the framework has a better solution. One other method is to use the Fluent Query Builder and create your own query but I don't see how that would be better.

Comment: But i l9ke a solution in one access to database not a foreach solution

Comment: @CRIMUVI I extended my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Define a *hasManyThrough* relationship in User::find(1)->roles()->tools

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function tools()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Tool', 'Role');
    }
}
```

Then you can access straight forward:

```
$user->tools
```

Comment: This doesn't  work, your solution is not for manyto many relations, giveme that the column roles.user_id don't exist.